# Getting a specific String from List.generate with onTap

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart

I am using WordPress REST API to fetch posts from a WordPress site with this piece of code with the help of [wordpress_api](https://pub.dev/packages/wordpress_api) package.

```
class ProvideTitle with ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> Titles = [];
  List<String> Descriptions = [];
  List<String> Urls = [];

void ClearTitle() { //clears lists when called
  Titles.clear();
  Descriptions.clear();
  Urls.clear();
}

void TitleFetcher(term) async { //takes term from query and adds parameters

 final String searchTerm=term;
  final api = WordPressAPI('https://wordpresswebsite.com');
  WPResponse res = await api.posts.fetch(args: {
    "search" : searchTerm,
    "per_page" : "20",
    "page" : "1"

  });
  for (final post in res.data){ //returns String to fill Lists below for each post found
    Titles.add(post.title);
    Descriptions.add(post.content);
    Urls.add(post.link);
  }
  notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Everything is working as expected and class notifies all listeners with each List<//Strings> respectively.

Problem here is I build a list with List.generate using List<//String> Title in search bar recommendations with [material_floating_search_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar), code looks like this.

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
 const SearchPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SearchPageState();
}

class SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {//search bar from package mentioned
  late String resultValue= "";
  final controller = FloatingSearchBarController(); //controller for search bar
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Consumer<ProvideTitle>(builder: (context, provideTitle, child) {//Provider used for listening to ProvideTitle class
        return FloatingSearchBar(
            debounceDelay: const Duration(milliseconds: 165),
            onQueryChanged: (query) async { //registers keyboard input
              query != "" ? provideTitle.TitleFetcher(query) //sends input to TitleFetcher function inside ProvideTitle class
              : provideTitle.ClearTitle(); //clears lists to stop showing fetced data with empty query(please feel free to recommend me a better way to do)
            },
            controller: controller,
            hint: "Search",
            backdropColor: Colors.transparent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            builder: (context, _) => BuildBody(), //calls list builder as recommendations
            body: resultValue != "" ? SearchResults(): //result body going to be called when some entry chosen from list
        SizedBox());//page stays empty when there is no action
      }),
    );
  }

  Widget BuildBody() {
    ProvideTitle model = Provider.of<ProvideTitle>(context); //ProvideTitle called for its lists as model
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      child: Material(
        child: Column(
          children:
              List.generate(model.Titles.length, (index) => model.Titles[index].toString()) //list generated as long as Title[index] which is 20 max because we only call 20 post from api
                  .map((e) => ListTile(
                onTap: () { // i want this onTap to register which tile I chosed
                  model.ClearTitle();//clears lists for next search
                  controller.close();//closes search bar recommendations
                },
                        title: Text(e),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After that list generated based on search, I want to chose one of the tiles to build a widget that contains fetched content of that post.

I created a class for contents to be displayed based on the tile we've chosen earlier but everything is also okay with that class.

How can I effectively call my class to show tiles contents that I chosen earlier, preferably without further fetching to stop wasting server resources and my devices resources.

I am completely new at flutter and developing this app for not more than three weeks without any previous coding experience other than few basic java apps that works on console, so please please please feel free to correct me in any way rather it's about my problem or not. Much thanks in advance.

Also this is my first question on here so excuse if formatting is not adequate enough for site.

Answer (score 0):

Using indexOf() successfully returns the int value of chosen tile.

```
List.generate(model.titles.length,
                (index) => model.titles[index].toString())
            .map((e) => ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {});
                    controller.close();
                    model.resultValue = model.titles.indexOf(e); // we are returning the int value of chosen tile to another class here
                    model.parsData();
                    model.clearFetchedData();
                  },
                  title: Text(e),
                ))
            .toList(),
```